# C# connection to webservice

Tags: c#

I have the following code. I need to make a connection to a URL and 
POST some data and need to get some data back.
Here is my code :

```
class  Data
{
 private  int id;
 private  string date; 
}



private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string URL = "URL";

            Data d = new Data();
            d.id = 12345678;
            d.date = "25-10-2019";
            string Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);

            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Data))
            {
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = "POST";

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(Data);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse webresponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    MessageBox.Show(response);
                }
            }
        }
```

By the statment : using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))

I got the error **System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.'**

And by the statement **using (HttpWebResponse webresponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)**
I got the error "System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.' "

Please help.

Comment: Try using HttpClient if you are calling an API.

Comment: That error occurs at the server side, you need to check the reason there.

Comment: Do you use postman app to call the url?

Comment: No, I do not use postman app.